# How to show custom ui in xamarin.auth FormAuthenticator?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.auth

I have a xamarin.android project and using xamarin.auth custom FormAuthenticator. I want to show my custom login view instead of default login view (`auth.GetUI(this)`) but all of the tutorials and code samples are about using oauth (facebook, google, twitter, ...)

Is there any code sample?

Comment: What did you go with in the end?

Comment: @noelicus just create your ui and use `AccountStore.Create().Save(account, "YourServiceId");`